# Self-join a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to use `INNER JOIN` on one table. But I get this error message:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'a'.

My query is :

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GoodMainCode) as row 
     from [SarMem].[dbo].[Book_Data1]  
     where GoodName like '%A%' and GroupCode = 115) a 
  inner join a b on b.GoodMainCode = a.GoodMainCode 
where a.row > 0 and a.row <= 100
```

**updated**

[image]

Comment: a  table is an alias .

Comment: Given b is a real table name, swap your join about e.g. select * From B inner join(some query) a on a.id = b.id.  If b is an alias, an alias of what?

Comment: @marc_s, I think b is just an alias for a here

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: highly confusing - but you're right .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with cte:

```
;with a as(select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GoodMainCode) as row 
           from [SarMem].[dbo].[Book_Data1]  
           where GoodName like '%A%' and GroupCode = 115) 
 select * from a
 join a b on b.GoodMainCode = a.GoodMainCode
 where a.row > 0 and a.row <= 100
```

Comment: but it dost work well. for example, I have three recode from same value of GoodMainCode. updated my question.

Comment: Add some test data and expected result. It is not clear what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that?

```
WITH List AS (
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GoodMainCode) AS Row, *  
FROM
    [SarMem].[dbo].[Book_Data1]
WHERE
    ( GoodName like '%A%' )
    AND ( GroupCode = 115 )
) 
SELECT *  FROM List WHERE Row between 1 and 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here `a` is an alias name not the table name. So SQL SERVER won't allow `a` to create one more alias `b`.

So if you wanna use same table as `a`, then you have to rewrite subquery for `b` also.

Like,

```
select * from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GoodMainCode) as row from [SarMem].[dbo].[Book_Data1]  where GoodName like '%A%'  and GroupCode = 115  ) a 
 INNER  JOIN (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GoodMainCode) as row from [SarMem].[dbo].[Book_Data1]  where GoodName like '%A%'  and GroupCode = 115  ) b on b.GoodMainCode = a.GoodMainCode where  a.row > 0 and a.row <= 100
```